# What clustering algorithms are most similar to how humans cluster data?

Tags: decision-making

Clustering algorithms group unlabelled data, such as in the following example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSFTM.png]

Which clustering algorithms are similar to how humans do clustering? (e.g. Connectivity based clustering (hierarchical clustering), Centroid-based clustering, Distribution-based clustering, Density-based clustering, and so on).

Comment: What do you mean by "how humans cluster data"?

Comment: I'll expand on @ChristianHummeluhr and ask, what kind of data? in what context? Humans use varying heuristics in different contexts and for differing kinds of data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is on statistics and math

Comment: Let me know if you find an answer to this. I'd be curious to know, as well.

Comment: there is a good deal of research on human clustering of data (AKA categorization).  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3974273/?tool=pmcentrez http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21038975 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exemplar_theory.  Here's a paper that explicitly connects human category learning to machine learning http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18488638

Comment: To improve the question, you need a line somewhere to link it directly to cognitive sciences.